# $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y+\tan^{-1}z=\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}$ true for all $x$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y+\tan^{-1}z=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}$ true for all $x$ ?

This expression is found without mentioning the domain of $x,y,z$, but I don't think its true for all $x,y,z$ as the case with the expression for $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y$, but I have trouble proving it.

So what is the complete expression for $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y+\tan^{-1}z$ ?

\begin{align}
\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y+\tan^{-1}z&=
\begin{cases}\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)+\tan^{-1}z, &xy < 1 \\[1.5ex] 
\pi + \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)+\tan^{-1}z, &xy>1,\:\:x,y>0 \\[1.5ex] 
-\pi + \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)+\tan^{-1}z, &xy>1,\:\:x,y<0 \end{cases}\\
&=
\end{align}

Comment: Well ... apart from restrictions of a similar nature that apply to the arguments of the formula for two variables ie in that case xy<1 . I seem to remember, when I once checked this out for the general case of n variables, that you get the _odd_ symmetric polynomials of degree ≤ n in the numerator & the even symmetric [ _ditto_ ] in the denominator ... something like that, anyway.

Comment: I'm beginning to get the gist of your question now I think - I glossed over it a bit at first ... are you saying that when you go beyond two variables you _lose_ the property of it being valid ∀ possible values of whatever variables it imports (provided the other branches of _atn_ be admitted) ... that _even if you do_ admit these other branches that property ceases _by reason of_ going from two to three variables? That would be strange if it were so, and I would not have thought it were so ... but I can see how it might actually be something we can't safely assume by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

- $L(x,y,z) = \tan^{-1} x + \tan^{-1} y + \tan^{-1} z$
- $R(x,y,z) = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+y+z - xyz}{1- xy - yz - zx}\right)$

By addition formula of tangent function, we have 
$$\tan L(x,y,z) = \tan R(x,y,z)$$
Since $\tan \theta$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$, there is an integer valued function $N(x,y,z)$ such that $$L(x,y,z) = R(x,y,z) + N(x,y,z)\pi$$

Since $\tan^{-1}\theta$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, we have
$$|L(x,y,z)| < \frac{3\pi}{2} \land  |R(x,y,z)| < \frac{\pi}{2}\quad\implies\quad N(x,y,z) \in \{ 0, \pm 1 \}$$

Since $\tan^{-1} \theta$ is a continuous function for all $\theta$,
$N(x,y,z)$ will be constant over those domain where $xy+yz+zx \ne 1$.
Notice 
$$xy+yz+zx = 1 \iff 3\left(\frac{x+y+z}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2 - ( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ) = 2$$
is the equation of a two sheet hyperboloid centered at origin with symmetric axis pointing along the direction $(1,1,1)$. The complement of this hyperboloid consists of $3$ connected components. One can pick a point from each of these component and figure out the value of $N(x,y,z)$ over the whole component.

The end result is

$$L(x,y,z) = R(x,y,z) + \begin{cases} 
\pi, & 1 < xy+yz+zx \land x+y+z > 0\\
0,   & 1 > xy+yz+zx\\
-\pi & 1 < xy+yz+zx \land x+y+z < 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: thanx, i have difficulty in understanding the derivation, though i am working on it. Mean time I have checked for the case where $x=\sqrt{3},y=1,z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. We have $xy+yz+zx=3.30>1$ and $x+y+z>0$. LHS=$\frac{\pi}{3}+\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{3\pi}{4}$. RHS=$\pi+\tan^{-1}(-1)=\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{3\pi}{4}$=LHS. THus, verified !

Comment: I think I see. Obviously if x>0, y>0, & xy >1, in the expression with the single arctan & rational function as argument, the arctan is going to need to be taken to be the next 'occurence' of it - the 'branch' (if I've used that term strictly correctly) that goes from π/2 to 3π/2. If you allow that, the values of x & y are unrestricted ... is that so - have I understood it aright? I've tended to neglect this kind of thing a bit, as I've found that in situations where this addition formula arises, the values of x & y tend to be such as to obviate the need to bring 'other branches' into it.

Comment: Are you saying that _you can_ have any value of x y & z, ie _any_ point in xyz space? That the sheets of the hyperboloid are the surfaces that when (x,y,z) crosses it  changes value, being -1 inside the negative 'lobe', +1 inside the positive lobe, & 0 between the two lobes; but that no restriction is imposed on what (x,y,z) might _actually be_? That for _three_ variables _three_ branches of _atn_ are sufficient to take care of _all_ (x,y,z)? If (x,y,z)→(∞,∞,∞) then the extreme upper edge of the top branch; & if (-∞,-∞,-∞) the the extreme _lower_ edge of the _bottom_ branch?

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey Yes, aside from the restriction that $xy+yz+zx \ne 1$, there is no other restriction on $(x,y,z)$. If you look at the function $\tan^{-1}\theta$, it is well behaved for all finite $\theta$. The only place the $N(x,y,z)$ can change value is when $(x,y,z)$ cross the hyperboloid.

Comment: I can see something else: every time you introduce a new variable, the numerator & the denominator _alternate_ between having the higher degree polynomial - so as _all_ the variables go of to ∞ the _atn_ alternates between going to 0 & π/2, and likewise for -∞; so the _range_ of _atn_ increases by half the range of a branch above & below each time.

Comment: Right Thanks for that. There's loads of stuff I've glossed over in my time, one of which is _branches_ & _sheets_ & _cuts_, & all that. It suddenly looks a bit less _scary_ now than it did before!

Comment: I'd like to put something to you though - I can't expound the reasoning in these little comment spaces; but unless I've made a blunder somewhere, I'm _fairly_ sure that the lobes of this hyperbola are not asymptotic to a _right_ cone (ie one with the surface making angle π/4 with its axis), but rather to a _flatter_ cone - one of which the surface makes an angle _atn(√2)_ to its axis. ¶ My thoughts on this are ongoing - I'm not asking you to crunch through any algebra to verify it ... but I thought you _might_ just know straight-off, having clearly thought on this particular matter more than I

Comment: @AmbretteOrrisey yes, you are correct.

Comment: Yep thanks - I'm glad to know I'm not setting myself up a misleading figure!

Comment: What land symbol mean here? That upside straw one.

Comment: @user541396 are you referring to the symbol $\land$?  it is logical and.

Answer (score 2):

> This follows from the fact the the argument of a product of complex numbers is the sum of the arguments of the factors.

Let $\alpha=\arctan x$, $\beta=\arctan y$ and $\gamma=\arctan z$. These are the arguments of the complex numbers $z_1=1+ix$, $z_2=1+iy$ and $z_3=1+iz$ respectively.

In light of the above fact we see that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ is the argument 
(up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$) of the product 
$$
z_1z_2z_3=(1+ix)(1+iy)(1+iz)=(1-xy-yz-zx)+i(x+y+z-xyz).
$$
But the argument $\phi$ of a complex number $a+ib$ satisfies $\tan\phi=b/a$.

The claim follows from this.

> Just be mindful of the lingering uncertainty in the value of the inverse tangent up to an integer multiple of $\pi$. For example, if $x=y=z=1$ we have $\arctan x=\arctan y=\arctan z=\pi/4$ giving $3\pi/4$ on the left hand side. But, $x+y+z-xyz=2$, $1-xy-yz-zx=-2$, so we have $\arctan(-1)=-\pi/4$ on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

We have that by [**addition formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)

$$\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y=\tan^{-1}\frac{x+y}{1-xy}$$

then

$$(\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y)+\tan^{-1}z=\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{x+y}{1-xy}+z}{1-\frac{(x+y)z}{1-xy}}$$

the simplify to the given identity, which could be not well defined for (to check)

- $1-xy=0$

and is certainly not well defined for

- $1-xy-yz-zx=0$

Comment: so u saying the above expression is true for all $x,y,z$ except $xy=1,yz=1,zx=1$ and $xy+yz+zx=1$.

Comment: @ss1729 Maybe I could be more precise, what I'm claiming is that how we have obtained the equality those point could be problematic and then we need to check those cases directly. For exmaple the last one always is requested. I didn't chek the others.

Comment: @ss1729 I see know the the secon one was equivalent to the first + third! I've updated that.

Answer (score 0):

Write $a:=\arctan x$ etc. so $$\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}=\frac{\tan a+\tan b + (1-\tan a\tan b)\tan c}{1-\tan a\tan b - (\tan a+\tan b)\tan c}.$$If $xy\ne 1$, we can cancel $1-\tan a\tan b$ to get $$\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}=\frac{\tan (a+b)+\tan c}{1-\tan (a+b)\tan c}.$$If $\tan (a+b)\tan c\ne 1$ i.e. $(x+y)z\ne 1-xy$ i.e. $xy+yz+zx=1$, we have $$\frac{x+y+z-xyz}{1-xy-yz-zx}=\tan (a+b+c).$$We want to get $a+b+c$ from that, which isn't as simple as taking arctangents; it has the subtleties claimed in your question (albeit not the title).